# Function for Tidying Chisq.Test Output with Standard Evaluation

Tags: r, purrr, tidyverse

```
library(ggmosaic)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
```

This question is an extension to a previous answer provided by Jake Kaupp (link below).

[Function for Tidy chisq.test Output for Visualizing or Filtering P-Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840460/function-for-tidy-chisq-test-output-for-visualizing-or-filtering-p-values/41841760#41841760)

I would like to turn the code below into a function using standard evaluation so that I can create tidy chisq.test results across different variables. The code below uses "happy$happy" in the map row to look for associations between the "happy" variable and other categorical variables. The function would allow me to change "happy" to another variable, for example, "health" or "marital".

I would like to include the last "unnest" line within the function as well so that it returns the tidy chisq.test results.

```
df <- happy %>%
select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)  %>%
map(~chisq.test(.x,happy$happy))%>%
tibble(names=names(.),data=.) %>%
mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))

unnest(df,stats)
```

Comment: I've tried things like - Fun<-function(Var)%>%select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>%map(~chisq.test(.x, Var)%>%tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%mutate(stats=map(data,tidy)). I'm still new to standard evaluation and not sure how to approach the purrr::map functions with SE as well as the "happy$happy" part? I played around with variations of the example in this comment but couldn't get anything to work. I know dplyr verbs have SE versions, but not sure about map or tibble?

Comment: When I've used SE before with tidyr and dplyr, I used SE verbs, for example, gather becomes gather_, count becomes count_, etc, and used quotes for variables that are dynamic. But for this question, I'm not quite sure about map and tibble as SE, or where or what to quote?

Comment: For the first comment, I meant to write this...I forgot the { }   Fun<-function(Var){happy%>%select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>%map(~chisq.test(.x, Var)%>%tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))}.

Comment: Add what you tried to the question. It is unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just substitute `happy$happy` with `happy[,"happy"]`, which will allow you to do:

```
chifun <- function(var) {
       df <- happy %>% select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>%
                map(~chisq.test(.x,happy[,var]))%>%
                tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%
                mutate(stats=map(data,tidy)) %>% unnest(stats)
       return(df)
}

chifun("happy")
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears the bounty is yours. I'm so used to using "$" that I forget about "[ ]". I have a question, why don't I have to use any standard evaluation in this function? In previous functions I've had to use SE versions of verbs, such as "gather_" or "count_", as well as quotes, etc. How come none of that is necessary in this example?

Comment: That's because you are not passing any column names as strings to any of the `tidyverse` functions.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you used "df<-" and "return(df)", but that the code works without using these parts as well. Is there a reason to include them?

Comment: Finally, this last question is larger, so if you want me to create a new question for it so you can get credit for providing the answer, just let me know, but I'll include it here in the comment anyways. How do I use "return" to return two things - the tidy tibble as well as a plot? This code doesn't work: hifun<-function(var){
+ df<-happy%>%select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>%
+ map(~chisq.test(.x,happy[,var]))%>%
+ tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%
+ mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))%>%unnest(stats)
+ GG<-ggplot(df)+
+ geom_col(aes_string(x="names",y="p.value"))
+ return(df,GG)

Comment: Chifun<-function(var){
df<-happy%>%select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>%
map(~chisq.test(.x,happy[,var]))%>%
tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%
mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))%>%unnest(stats)
GG<-ggplot(df)+
geom_col(aes_string(x="names",y="p.value"))
return(df,GG)
 }

Comment: Code above doesn't work...I feel like something like that should work to return the tidy tibble from the original code as well as a plot?

Comment: Its good practice to assign objects calculated inside a function and consequently return them. As for your other comment please ask a new question.

Comment: I posted a new question - titled "Returning More Than One Object in a Function - a Tidy Chisq.Test Tibble and Ggplot". I can't offer another bounty lol, but your help would be appreciated!