# Run a aov test through a tibble in a tidy way

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to run a linear regression on a data frame using the same dependent variable. A similar question was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841760/7654451). The problem is that `aov` function to implement ANOVA doesn't accept `x` and `y` as arguments (as far as I know). Is there a way to implement the analysis in a tidy way? So far I've tried something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Species) %>% 
  mutate(foo_a = as_factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), nrow(.), replace = T)),
         foo_b = as_factor(sample(c("d", "e", "f"), nrow(.), replace = T))) %>% 
  map(~aov(Sepal.Length ~ .x, data = .))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The desired output is three analysis: `Sepal.Length` and `Species`, `Sepal.Length` and `foo_a` and the last one `Sepal.Length` and `foo_b`. Is it possible or I am totally wrong?

Comment: Look at purrr. Can't test now.

Comment: You could reshape to long data, nest on the combined `Species`/`foo_a`/`foo_b` column, and use the [many models](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) method

Comment: @camille could you explain a little more your answer? I was thinking to work with nested data but can't find the right way...

Comment: @TitoSanz. In case you are not interested in the solution below, please let me know.  I can delete it

Comment: @akrun I am interested in your solution but the solution proposed implied that I give all factor variables as list to `map2` function. My real dataset has 25 predictor variables numeric and factors so I am trying to figure out how to give something like `is.factor` or select only factor variables plus dependant and pass all as independent...

Comment: @akrun I very appreciate your answer but I accepted the other one which does not imply creating a temporary file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make this into a long-shaped data frame, group by the independent variable of interest, and use the ["many models"](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) approach. I usually prefer something like this over trying to do tidyeval across multiple columns—it just gives me a clearer sense of what's going on.

To save space, I'm working with `iris_foo`, which is your data as you created it up through the 2 mutate lines. Putting it into a long format gives you a key of the names of those three columns that will be used as independent variables in each of the `aov` calls.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris_foo %>%
  gather(key, value, -Sepal.Length)

#> # A tibble: 450 x 3
#>    Sepal.Length key     value 
#>           <dbl> <chr>   <chr> 
#>  1          5.1 Species setosa
#>  2          4.9 Species setosa
#>  3          4.7 Species setosa
#>  4          4.6 Species setosa
#>  5          5   Species setosa
#>  6          5.4 Species setosa
#>  7          4.6 Species setosa
#>  8          5   Species setosa
#>  9          4.4 Species setosa
#> 10          4.9 Species setosa
#> # … with 440 more rows
```

From there, nest by `key` and create a new list-column of ANOVA models. This will be a list of `aov` objects. For simplicity with getting your models back out, you can drop the data column.

```r
aov_models <- iris_foo %>%
  gather(key, value, -Sepal.Length) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~aov(Sepal.Length ~ value, data = .))) %>%
  select(-data)

aov_models
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   key     model    
#>   <chr>   <list>   
#> 1 Species <S3: aov>
#> 2 foo_a   <S3: aov>
#> 3 foo_b   <S3: aov>
```

From there, you can work with the models however you like. They're accessible in the list `aov_models$model`. Printed, they look how you'd expect. For example, the first model:

```r
aov_models$model[[1]]
#> Call:
#>    aov(formula = Sepal.Length ~ value, data = .)
#> 
#> Terms:
#>                    value Residuals
#> Sum of Squares  63.21213  38.95620
#> Deg. of Freedom        2       147
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.5147894
#> Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

To see all the models, call `aov_models$model %>% map(print)`. You might also want to use `broom` functions, such as `broom::tidy` or `broom::glance`, depending on how you need to present the models.

```r
aov_models$model %>%
  map(broom::tidy)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   term         df sumsq meansq statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 value         2  63.2 31.6        119.  1.67e-31
#> 2 Residuals   147  39.0  0.265       NA  NA       
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   term         df   sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 value         2   0.281  0.141     0.203   0.817
#> 2 Residuals   147 102.     0.693    NA      NA    
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   term         df   sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 value         2   0.756  0.378     0.548   0.579
#> 2 Residuals   147 101.     0.690    NA      NA
```

Or tidying all the models into a single data frame, which keeps the `key` column, you could do:

```r
aov_models %>%
  mutate(model_tidy = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>%
  unnest(model_tidy)
```

Comment: This makes total sense! Thanks